# Помогите пожалуйста внедрить php-код в javascript и отправить его в обработчик

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста внедрить php-код в javascript и отправить его в обработчик

Есть код

```css
.ychreditel {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <script language='JavaScript' type="text/javascript">
  var obrabotchik = '<?php require ("obrabotchik.php"); ?>'
  var i = 2;
  function ff(){
    document.getElementById('form_inner').innerHTML = document.getElementById('form_inner').innerHTML +
  "<select name='country" + i + "' class='ychreditel'>"+ obrabotchik +"</select>";
  i++;
  }

</script>
 
 <form name='form' id='form' action='fff.php' method='post'>
  <span name='form_inner' id='form_inner'>
   <select name='country1' class='ychreditel'><?require ('obrabotchik.php');?></select>
  </span>
  <input type='button' value='Добавить учредителя' onclick="ff()">
  <input name='frm_sbm' type='submit' value='Submit request' />
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку Добавить учредителя должен добавиться select  с содержимым файла obrabotchik.php

Файл
require ('obrabotchik.php'); содержит код (код сокращен)

```
echo = "
<option> Австралия</option>
<option> Австрия</option>
<option> Азербайджан</option> 
<option> Албания</option>
<option> Ангола</option>
<option> Андорра</option>
";
```

Пробовал объявить переменную js и присвоить ей значение php

```
var obrabotchik = '<?php require ("obrabotchik.php"); ?>'
```

В результате скрипт перестаёт работать

И подскажите пожалуйста как можно обработать новые select в fff.php

Спасибо!

Comment: Обычно такое делают через AJAX, умеете ?

Comment: Пока знаю только html css и php, до js я ещё не добрался. JS-код взял на просторах интернета

Comment: Необходимо по клику или другому события выполнить AJAX запрос, получить данные и заполнить ими Ваш элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого примера jQuery нид.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'obrabotchik.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (countriesList) {
        countriesList.forEach( function (country) {
            $('#country1').append("<option>" + country + "</option>");
        });
    }
});
```

И в php файле

```
echo json_encode("
<option> Австралия</option>
<option> Австрия</option>
<option> Азербайджан</option> 
<option> Албания</option>
<option> Ангола</option>
<option> Андорра</option>
");
```

Ajax запрос закинуть в нужное событие, например, при загрузке страницы. Итого получим: страница загрузилась, JS сделал запрос на  `obrabotchik.php` и получил оттуда `json` со списком. После этого циклом прошелся по элементам и каждый добавил внутрь вашего select'a

Comment: При срабатывании функции ff() должен создаваться новый select c name="country2" и два input c type="radio" и name="visa2".
То есть после каждого нажатия на кнопку Добавить учредителя, цифра в конце country и visa должна увеличиваться. Чтобы потом можно было обработать эти поля

Comment: Поместите в переменную this.responeText

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` это API, который предоставляет клиенту функциональность для обмена данными между клиентом и сервером. Данный API предоставляет простой способ получения данных по ссылке без перезагрузки страницы. Это позволяет обновлять только часть веб-страницы не прерывая пользователя.  `XMLHttpRequest используется в AJAX запросах и особенно в single-page приложениях.`

XMLHttpRequest изначально был разработан Microsoft и позже заимствован Mozilla, Apple, и Google. Сейчас он стандартизирован WHATWG. Несмотря на свое название, `XMLHttpRequest` может быть использован для получения любых типов данных, не только XML, и поддерживает протоколы помимо [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP) (включая `file` и [ftp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/FTP)).

### Как работать с AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)

Чтобы начать работать с `XMLHttpRequest`, выполните этот код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Где `xhr` это переменная которой присвоили `new XMLHttpRequest()` буквально мы просто присвоили что она будет выполнять запросы `XMLHttpRequest`. В этом отрывке кода вы увидите ajax на примере

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById('form_inner').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "obrabotchik.php", true);
  xhr.send();
```

Разберем все по порядку

- Про строчку `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` я рассказывал выше
- Строчка `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {` означает если так сказать XMLHttpRequest готов загрузить файл.
- Строчка `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {` означает что если все верно т.е `readyState == 4` означает что файл загружен а `status == 200` означает что никаких ошибок не найдено (например 404)
- Строчка `document.getElementById('form_inner').innerHTML = this.responseText;` здесь `responseText` это ответный текст от сервера т.е. что произошло после компиляции *php-файла*. в вашем случае это вот такой ответ

```
    <option> Австралия</option>
    <option> Австрия</option>
    <option> Азербайджан</option> 
    <option> Албания</option>
    <option> Ангола</option>
    <option> Андорра</option>
```

- Строчка `xhr.open("GET", "obrabotchik.php", true);` Это значит какой вы открываете файл (в вашем случае файл `obrabotchik.php`) и `GET` это тип запроса, если будут отправляться пароли или большие тексты то лучше использовать `POST`. `true` означает что запрос асинхронный
- Строчка `xhr.send();` Означает отправить запрос

---

Все что до заголовка *"Как работать с AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)"* было взято из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Как я понял строка xhr.send(); возвращает то, что мне нужно
Но как совместить её с функцией ff()?

Comment: а в чем проблема

Comment: в функции ff() есть строка
"<select name='country" + i + "' class='ychreditel'></select>";


я делаю так
"<select name='country" + i + "' class='ychreditel'>"+xhr.send();+"</select>";
Походу это делается не так)

Comment: Создайте переменную и присвойте ей this.responeText

Comment: Сделал так   var text = this.responseText;
После этого так:  
"<select name='country" + i + "' class='ychreditel'>"+text+"</select>";
Создаётся select name="'country2", но внутри него undefined

Comment: потому-что нужно делать внутри события onreadystatechange